# Eclipse Juno's content assist shows everything twice

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I just installed Eclipse Juno and configured the content assist next:

[image]

and everything appearing twice now:

[image]

**Some one know the right configuration for that?**

Comment: Do you have two JREs on the Java Build Path somehow?

Comment: I don't think so, I just deleted the old eclipse and strat working in new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java Proposals "kind" contains both the Java Type Proposals and the Java Non-Type Proposals. Either remove the Java Proposals, or the other two, and the duplications should be solved.